# A problem when I use webpack-5's libraryTarget:window

Tags: webpack, micro-frontend, single-spa, webpack-5

I'm using the single-spa to create my apps.
When I load the micro-frontend app, I did not use SystemJS, Just as follows:

```
export const runScript = async (url: string) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;

    const firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    (firstScript as any).parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
  });
};

const loadApp = async (appPath: string) => {
  try {
    await runScript(`/${appPath}/index.js`);
    console.log(appPath, '=', (window as any)[appPath]);
  } catch {
    console.log("load child app's javascript file error。");
  }
  return (window as any)[appPath];
};

singleSpa.registerApplication({
  name: 'app1',
  app: () => loadApp('app1'),
  activeWhen: '/app1,
  customProps: {
  },
});
```

So, I use `libraryTarget:'window'`  in app1's webpack config.

```
devServer: {
  //...
  libraryTarget:'window'
},
```

It works fine when I use webpack4.

But when I update the webpack to webpack-5, it appears to have something wrong, the output code generated by webpack can not set the right value to the window object.

webpack-4:
[works fine at webpack-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8hKr.png)

webpack-5:
[nothing in the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sHw6.png)

Is this a problem of webpack-5?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use webpack5 for my single-spa-angular components. I have `umd` as `libraryTarget`

```
 "customWebpackConfig": {
     "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
     "libraryName": "mylib",
     "libraryTarget": "umd"
 }
```

https://github.com/milobella/application-web/blob/master/spa-menu/angular.json#L36-L37

And my app is well here under `window` when load the script
https://github.com/milobella/application-web/blob/master/portal/src/main.ts#L9

Comment: Thank you, but React app use webpack-dev-server to start at local env,  seems it's the bug of 'webpack-dev-server'.

Comment: Ah sorry yes, indeed my answer is not relevant, I tried and angular custom webpack library is working fine with libraryTarget window

I found the issue you created on webpack-dev-server https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2783 
I guess you wait for a fix to share it on this post